# how to replace backslash character with double backslash in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, backslash

I'm trying to replace backslashes in my string with two backslashes like so:

```
s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

But, it doesn't do anything. Example string:

```
s="\r\nHi\r\n";
```

Comment: when you print the string (before the replace), does it show one or two backslashes?

Comment: @user2049371 one more option posted

Comment: The string in your example (`"\r\nHi\r\n"`) does not contain a backslash. `\r` is the escape sequence for a carriage return and `\n` is the escape sequence for a line feed. The resulting string value does not contain the backslash character. Just do `console.log(s)` and you will see. If you'd explain what problem you are really trying to solve, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @user2049371 What Felix said is correct, the string does't contain escape sequences. View my example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wC8Cc/29/

Comment: very very tanks . to worke following code :s = s.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string doesn't contain a backslash, it contains the `\r` escape sequence.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wC8Cc/32/)

For example

```
var str = "\r\n";
var replaced = str.replace('\r\n', '\\r\\n');
alert(replaced);
```

Then the alert will be shown `\r\n`

Comment: @user2049371 one more option posted

Comment: for help =>    s = "\r\n" ;